# wicket DatePicker - show last select value

Tags: wicket, yui, wicket-6

I am using  org.apache.wicket.datetime.markup.html.form.DateTextField (part of wicket-datetime-6.9.0-sources.jar ) with wicket 6.9.0

I need the DatePicker to auto select the last selected value, when it is opened an empty value.

As it is, when I open the date picker with an empty value no date is selected.

Last selected value, means , lets say somone choose 1.1.2019 so the next time the datepicker instance will b opened from another date field the value would show 1.1.2019

Comment: what do you mean with "the last selected value"?

Comment: Do you specifically want the field to be filled in when the datepicker is opened up, or is it okay for it to be generated with the page itself and then displayed?

Comment: I want the date picker would be filled with data from the last selected e.g given 1.1.2019 i would want it to be opened in 01.01.2019 and not on today as it today.